# How to disable Click through to a NSView behind another NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I have two NSViews on top of each other. One NSView presents a table with rows. On clicking a  row another view is shown on top of that view.

Now the problem is when I click on an area on the second view where there is a row on the underneath NSView then it gets clicked. How can I stop that?

Thanks

Answer (score -9, accepted):

You can enable touch and mouse events in the top view when it is presented:

```
topView.acceptsTouchEvents = YES;
topView.acceptsFirstMouse = YES;
```

**Edit:** the comment is correct that `acceptsFirstMouse` isn't a property, and must be  updated in a subclass.

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work. I couldn't find acceptsFirstMouse property on NSView.

Comment: @PeterDeWeese, it seems you have to subclass and return YES in `acceptsFirstMouse` because it isn't a property of NSView.

Comment: Got no idea about this chaps but I solved my problem by changing the design. Thanks

Comment: @Leo, why did you accept the answer if it didn't work?

Comment: Probably because accepting answers gives points to both guys ;)

Comment: I'll delete my answer to reduce confusion.... Actually I can't because it is accepted. I did add a second one. Feel free to flesh out.

Answer (score 17):

On your top level view, implement `mouseDown:` in that view and do not call nextResponder or do anything in it.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    //Do nothing to not propagate the click event to descendant views   
}
```

I have the exact same scenario as the OP and this is working for me as intended. Credit to the answer I found [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg45005.html) that led me to this.

Comment: This works, but I've noticed the mouse cursor still changes to show whatever action (edit text, click button, etc.) is behind the top `NSView`. Is there a way to totally block the interaction?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Subclass and implement `acceptsFirstMouse` in the view, returning `YES`. Also, set `acceptsTouchEvents` to `YES` in that view.

```
import Cocoa
class UnView: NSView{
    override func acceptsFirstMouse(for event: NSEvent?) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    override var allowedTouchTypes: NSTouch.TouchTypeMask {
        get { return [] }
        set { }
    }
}
```